# Vagrant ssh with 'ubuntu' user on ubuntu/bionic64 18.04 box

Tags: vagrant

I am trying to ssh as **ubuntu** user on **ubuntu/bionic64** box version **20181024.0.0**, using this Vagrant file:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.box_version = "20181024.0.0"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.24.25"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
  end

end
```

When doing `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh`, I am logged in as **vagrant** user. If this line is added:

```
config.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'
```

to get a Vagrantfile like this:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.box_version = "20181024.0.0"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.24.25"

  config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
  end

end
```

and running `vagrant up`, I'm getting the authentication error message:

```
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I have also tried adding this line

```
config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
```

But that doesn't work either.

I am aware that the user can be changed once ssh'd into the vm as `vagrant` user, but I'd like that to be done automatically, as is the case when using **ubuntu/xenial64** version **20171011.0.0** with default configuration.

Any ideas how to workaround this?

**Vagrant version**: 2.2.0

**VirtualBox version**: 5.2.20 r125813

The whole output is:

```
danilo$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/bionic64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'ubuntu/bionic64' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ubuntu-bionic64_default_1540543288462_93774
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: ubuntu
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Comment: did you execute `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` after change configuration, because `config.ssh.username = 'ubuntu'` should work. If you can refer to full Vagrantfile it will be useful too

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Yes, I did `vagrant destroy` before making changes and `vagrant up` again. I've updated the contents of the Vagrantfile, that's all there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instruction based on https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OXA/pages/157802739/Vagrant+is+stuck+Authentication+failure.+Retrying...

in short

1. comment `config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"` in Vagrantfile
2. `vagrant up` \\ setup VM with default vagrant user
3. get  `IdentityFile` path value from result of command `vagrant ssh-config`
4. generate key `ssh-keygen -y -f <!!path-from-IdentityFile!!>`, copy this key
5. `vagrant ssh`   \\ you will auth under vagrant user for a while
6. `sudo -u ubuntu bash` \\ change user
7. `vim ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, add key from 4.
8. exit from VM
9. uncomment `config.ssh.username = "ubuntu"` in Vagrantfile
10. `vagrant reload`
11. `vagrant ssh` \\ you will auth under ubuntu user now

Comment: Thanks. I expected there to be an easier way, but I guess it's just the matter of how the box was created in the first place.